# Arrays of arrays of hashes Why does it copy the last hash reference to all elements in the same row

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to merge an an index file with 8 files additional files. The additional files are divided into two groups U and D, each group contains 4 files. The rows in additional files are basically and ID, from index file, and a few columns to be merged with the index file. To make it simple here, just one column is to be merged with the index file.

An array of array is defined, each element in this array of array included a hash with ids as key and respective item in the column as value. All sounds simple, I check the values and keys are added to this data structure correctly but when reading from the structure, it just includes info from U files added to D files, As if the last index to be added to the array element is copied to the element before it!!!

Here is my code, I am using an index ID, ENST00000504820.1, to show where it goes wrong:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;


my @direction = ("U", "D");
my @bins = (1..10);

my (@countBins);

foreach my $dir (@direction){
    foreach my $bin (@bins){

    my $hash = {};

    open EXPBIN , "bins/bin_$dir\_$bin\.txt" or die "Could not open bin file!";
    while(<EXPBIN>){

        next if ($. ==1);
        chomp();
        my @ar= split();

        $hash->{$ar[0]} = $ar[2];

        print "Bin\:$bin\tDir\:$dir\nIn the file: $ar[2]\tIn the hash:" . $hash->{$ar[0]} . "\n" if( $ar[0] =~ /ENST00000504820/);
    }       

    $countBins[$dir][$bin] = $hash;

    ## Debug
    print "In the array of array of hashes:" . $countBins[$dir][$bin]{"ENST00000504820.1"}. "\n\n"; 

}
}


open OUT , ">", "table.txt" or die "Could not open the output file!";
open LINC , "duke_h1_expression_dhs_chd_50_100.txt" or die "Could not open lincNRA file!";
while(<LINC>){

next if ($. ==1);
chomp();
print OUT $_; # Print this lincRNA to output
my @ar= split();

## Look up DHS in bins of this lincRNA  
foreach my $dir (@direction){
    foreach my $bin (@bins){

        if(exists $countBins[$dir][$bin]{$ar[4]}){

            print OUT "\t" . $countBins[$dir][$bin]{$ar[4]};

            print "Dir:$dir\tBin:$bin\t".$countBins[$dir][$bin]{$ar[4]} . "\n" if( $ar[4] =~ /ENST00000504820/);

        } else {

            print OUT "\t0";


        } 

    }
}

print OUT "\n";
}
```

I checked, they go in correctly but come out wrong! This is the output:

```
Bin:1   Dir:U
In the file: 0  In the hash:0
In the array of array of hashes:0

In the array of array of hashes:

Bin:3   Dir:U
In the file: 100    In the hash:100
In the array of array of hashes:100

Bin:4    Dir:U
In the file: 100    In the hash:100
In the array of array of hashes:100

Bin:1   Dir:D
In the file: 80 In the hash:80
In the array of array of hashes:80

Bin:2   Dir:D
In the file: 80 In the hash:80
In the array of array of hashes:80

Bin:3   Dir:D
In the file: 66.6666666666667   In the hash:66.6666666666667
In the array of array of hashes:66.6666666666667

Bin:4   Dir:D
In the file: 71.4285714285714   In the hash:71.4285714285714
In the array of array of hashes:71.4285714285714

Dir:U    Bin:1  80

Dir:U   Bin:2   80

Dir:U    Bin:3  66.6666666666667

Dir:U   Bin:4   71.4285714285714

Dir:D   Bin:1   80

Dir:D   Bin:2   80

Dir:D   Bin:3   66.6666666666667

Dir:D   Bin:4   71.4285714285714
```

Any idea why it copies one hash reference to another element in the two dimensional array?

Thanks,
Ava

Comment: Could you reduce your code to something more manageable. If you're going to read from a file, you should provide the contents of the file, but you should be able to demonstrate your particular problem without reading from a file.

Comment: Also, saying the output is wrong without saying what output you expect is not that helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `$dir` as in index for `@countBins` but `$dir` has the values `"U"` and `"D"` which are not numbers. `$countBins["U"]` and `$countBins["D"]` are both equivalent to `$countBins[0]`

There would have been a warning about this if you had them enabled.